# ProgressBar wirh label that follow the progressBar value

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I want to implement something like this:

[image]

So i have this `ProgreeBar`:

```
<ProgressBar
    Name="progressBar1"
    Value="0"
    Height="33"
    Width="300"
    Foreground="SkyBlue"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"             
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Margin="0,220,0,0"/>
```

And `Grid` with `Ellipse` and `TextBlock`:

```
<Grid Name="myGrid" Margin="0,100,0,0">
    <Ellipse
        Name="ellipse"
        Width="65"
        Height="65"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"             
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Stroke="SkyBlue"
        Fill="SkyBlue"
        Margin="-300,0,0,0" />
    <TextBlock
        Text="{Binding ElementName=progressBar1, Path=Value}"
        Foreground="White"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"             
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="16"
        Margin="-300,0,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

So this is the result:

[image]

Now every 1 second i want to increase my `ProgreeBar` `value` and i am using timer:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value += 4;
    myGrid.Margin = new Thickness((progressBar1.Value * 3 * 2), 100, 0, 0);
}
```

So this works fine:

[image]

But in some point this `Ellipse` is out of the correct position:

[image]

- Edit

I will glad to here another approach to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because you are changing the `Margin` which does what you told it to do when you resize the `Window` to smaller one. What you want to do is to use `RenderTransform`  and specify the `X` and `Y` coordinates relative to where you want it to be. It will be layout agnostic.

Here's how I would do it, (there can be improvements) but the idea is there.

```
 progressBar1.Value += 4;
 var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(progressBar1, 0) as Grid;
 if (grid != null)
 {
   var decorator = grid.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PART_Indicator");
   if (decorator != null)
      myGrid.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(decorator.ActualWidth, myGrid.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetY);
 }
```

What I did is I wanted to get the actual width of the control inside the `ProgressBar`. How did I know that? I used [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) tool to know what are the child controls. From there, I want to access the actual value of the `Grid` that holds the `Rectangle` that colors the progressbar and then I set the `X` to it's `ActualWidth`. Now this would work because this is assuming that the `ProgressBar` and the `Ellipse` is only the child control of the `MainWindow` where I know it is `centered`.

If my controls are not the `Points` that I am expecting then you need to do more work by transforming points relative to a Visual that you want. More information can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14895/WPF-Tutorial-Part-Transformations).

Full code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid >
        <ProgressBar 
    Name="progressBar1"
    Value="0"
    Height="33"
    Width="300"
    Foreground="SkyBlue"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"             
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Margin="0,220,0,0"/>
        <Grid Name="myGrid" Margin="0,100,0,0" >
            <Ellipse
        Name="ellipse"
        Width="65"
        Height="65"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"             
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Stroke="SkyBlue"
        Fill="SkyBlue"
        Margin="-300,0,0,0" />
            <TextBlock
        Text="{Binding ElementName=progressBar1, Path=Value}"
        Foreground="White"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"             
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="16"
        Margin="-300,0,0,0" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private FrameworkElement _decorator;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;

    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {

        _timer = new Timer(500);
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerOnElapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            progressBar1.Value += 4;
            var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(progressBar1, 0) as Grid;
            if (grid != null)
                _decorator = grid.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PART_Indicator");
            if (_decorator != null)
                myGrid.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(_decorator.ActualWidth, myGrid.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetY);
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see that now i have a delay, at the first time that the progress bar change the value the ellipse is still not moving and only in the second time when the progress time is changed value than the ellipse start to move and this create i small delay at the position

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should create a control template. Then you need to align your controls to the left. The margin needs to be calculated from the current with of the control and the range of the progress bar. The following should work

```
<Grid Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  <ProgressBar
      Name="progressBar1"
      Value="0"
      Height="33"
      Width="300"
      Foreground="SkyBlue"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Margin="32,220,32,0"/>

  <Border Name="myBorder" Margin="0,100,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CornerRadius="32" Width="64" Height="64" BorderBrush="SkyBlue" BorderThickness="1" Background="SkyBlue">
     <TextBlock
           Text="{Binding ElementName=progressBar1, Path=Value}"
           Foreground="White"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="16" />
  </Border>
</Grid>
```

And in your timer:

```
              this.progressBar1.Value += 4;
              var leftMargin = this.progressBar1.ActualWidth * this.progressBar1.Value / (this.progressBar1.Maximum - this.progressBar1.Minimum);
              this.myBorder.Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin, 100, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That won't work. It looks like it is working because you set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left`. If you change it to `Center` then you're off. Also, your calculations are weird. Where did you come up with that calculation?

Comment: Sure, left alignment is a must. The calculation is just normal % calculation of the position, Maximum - Minimum => Range of the value, ActualWidth => 100% in DeviceUnits. So it's just 100% * Value / ValueRange.